# Odd Draggable Behavior After Implementing Auto Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've implemented drag and drop using the [jQuery UI draggable widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/).

I'm now implementing auto scroll during drag operations. I set it up so that when you start to drag, gray overlays appear at the top and bottom of the browser window. When you drag into one of these overlays, the browser window starts to auto scroll.

You can see my test page at http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/scrolltest.html. Drag an item by dragging one of the crosshair icons on the left side.

But there's a problem: if you scroll to the bottom of the page, and then drag an item to the top overlay, it will scroll up as expected. However, for me, I get about half way up the page and the draggable helper won't go any higher. There's no way for me to drag all the way to the top of the page.

This most likely seems related to the Draggable widget. Is anyone able to see why this is happening? I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm using Chrome (22) and it seems to work for me. When I keep my dragged item in the top grey zone, it scrolls up the entire page. I then have to move my mouse (still dragging) down to drop it in the table of course. But works...

Comment: @Peter: Thanks. Looks like I have version Version 24.0.1312.52 m. Just tried it again, and this time I didn't even scroll a full page up before the dragged item won't go up any more. Any amount of moving the mouse at the point will not bring the item any higher. Did you drag all the way from the bottom to the top of the page?

Comment: Odd. I took the bottom most item, and held my cursor in the top grey zone. I can scroll all the way up, but I lose the item I'm dragging...

Comment: Why is that odd? Isn't that exactly the issue I'm describing?

Comment: FWIW, I took your code and upgraded to the latest jQuery and jQuery-UI and it still has the issue.

Comment: @Grinn: I was thinking the version I had was pretty recent, but thanks for checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the draggable containment option from window to document worked for me.

```
$('.drag-handle').draggable({ 
    ...
    containment: "document",
    ...
});
```

See: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-containment

Answer (score 3):

To be cross-browser compatible and to avoid wird behavior, I would recommend to use all [JQueryUI draggable callbacks](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/).

I read some days ago that the last version of Chrome has some really tricky problems with natives HTML5 draggable events.

For example, I have just checked your web page source code and you are using `$('.drag-handle').on('drag', function(){...});` => You should use the [drag](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag) callback.

I would also recommend to not use `window` as the scrollable container in your case. You should create a `div` to wrap all the tables contents and use it as a scroll container. I have already done this implementation in the past and it is working.

Don't forget to set the wrapper ID in the `containment` option durring the draggable widget creation.

If it always not working, you could also try to overwrite the helper position in the `drag` callback :

```
//Save the mouse position in global variables
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   window.mouseXPos = e.pageX;
   window.mouseYPos = e.pageY;
});

$('[id^="drag-"]').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
        opacity: 0.7,
        cursorAt: { top: 15, left: 50 },        
        scroll: true,
        stop: function(){},  
        drag : function(e,ui){            
            //Force the helper position
            ui.position.left = window.mouseXPos - $(this).draggable('option','cursorAt').left;
            ui.position.top = window.mouseYPos- $(this).draggable('option','cursorAt').top; 
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go over this. However, I don't believe that creating a scrollable div will be acceptable. That will make normal scrolling somewhat unnatural when I believe the page should have natural scrolling. In addition, when I go to the scrollable demos on the jQuery Draggable pages, I find quirky behavior there as well. This still seems to me to be an issue with the Draggable widget.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I see what difference using the callbacks would make. I saw the code related to your answer to my other question and how you check the mouse position. But I'm taking a different approach to this. And the dragging seems to be working just fine. (Unless I'm missing something.)

Comment: I would be interesting to check your solution out when you will figure this out. Keep in touch.