# Gridster autoscroll widget when element is dragged without moving mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoscroll, gridster

I'm using the gridster jquery plugin in my project. I have a few draggable widgets spread across many columns, which stretch far beyond the width of the viewport. I would like the viewport to autoscroll once a dragged widget comes close to the viewport bounds. Unfortunately, this only works when the mouse is being moved (it seems to be triggered by the change of position and not a mousedown event).

A demo... try to move a widget to the far right of the container: http://jsfiddle.net/pxa1h9j2/

HTML:

```
<div class="gridster">
    <div class="box" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></div>
    <div class="box" data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></div>
    <div class="box" data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></div>
    <div class="box" data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #333333;
}

.box {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gridster").gridster({
        widget_selector: '.box',
        widget_margins: [10, 10],
        widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
        min_cols: 30,
        max_cols: 30
    })
});
```

Does anybody know how I can get the autoscroll to work as I'd like?

Cheers,

Martin

Comment: fiddle link is missing...

Comment: Sorry for that. The link has been updated in the first post.

Comment: i don't understand what you're trying to achieve, what do you mean by "viewport to autoscroll"? Also, what do you expect the dragging to be triggered by if not the move of the mouse? mousedown is when you click the mouse, but if you're in the middle of dragging, you already have the mouse button clicked... i'm confused, to be honest...

Comment: Hi webeno. I have created a gridster element with 30 columns and I want to be able to comfortably drag a .box element from column 1 to column 30. Naturally, not all of the columns fit in the view so a scrollbar is necessary. When I drag a .box element to the right bound, I want the offset to change (autoscroll) even when the mouse isn't being moved. If it's still unclear, have a look at the answer in this thread: [CLICK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263676/implementing-auto-scroll-with-jquery-ui-draggable-widget). I want to be able to do the same using gridster.

Comment: well, you're going to have to try it on your own first, then if you're stuck with it, you can include it in your question... i suggest you delete this one though, as i have serious doubts anyone will answer it (in fact, it is a candidate for closure as you haven't actually tried anything), and open a new one once you have your tried code... this site is for troubleshooting existing code, not to write new for you...